# Can't use public static class, or don't know how to

Tags: c#, static

I have a public static class `Cashier`:

```
namespace MPP_TCP_Client
{
    public static class Cashier
    {
        public static IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

        public static TcpClient Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                return new TcpClient(Util.localAddrStr, Util.port);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", ane);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", se);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException nre)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Null Reference Exception: {0}", nre);
            }
            return null;
        }

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the `Connect` method:

```
namespace Mpp_TCP_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start client");
            Console.ReadKey();
            TcpClient whatever = Cashier.Connect(); // Cashier is not being seen by Visual Studio
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The namespaces are different? or is it just a typo?

Comment: the first namespace is called 'MPP_TCP_Client' and the second 'Mpp_TCP_Client'

Comment: Hmm no it's not. Seems to be a generation error. But after editing it, I think it now works

Comment: I compiles without errors for me and intellisense works like a charm.

Comment: Tested this in LinQPad and everything works.

Comment: Everything you have shown is syntactically valid. Except for the different casing in the namespaces, but that has been mentioned before + I'm not sure if namespaces are case sensitive. You're using static classes correctly, however :)

Comment: C# is case sensitive, so that difference in namespace will matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As Dennis_E mentioned above (I noticed his comment after I posted this answer):*

Your namespaces have different casing.

The `Cashier` class uses: `MPP_TCP_Client` and the `Program` class uses: `Mpp_TCP_Client`.

Try this which matches the namespaces:

```
namespace MPP_TCP_Client // This should now be the same as the Cashier class
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start client");
            Console.ReadKey();
            TcpClient whatever = Cashier.Connect(); // Cashier is not being seen by Visual     Studio
        }
    }
}
```

Or if this was intentional, add the following using statement:

```
using MPP_TCP_Client;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice it, though it is annoying because I didn't add the namespace myself (was generated) and I don't know what happened. Either way thanks.